# Can not open the RAW files of my new Canon 800D (t7i)

Tags: canon, raw, windows-10

A copule of months ago I got a new camera the canon 800D (t7i), and windows can not open the raw files (.CR2)  from the camera, I've tried installing the official canon raw codec and windows still can't show the thumbnails of the pictures, I've been converting my pictures to DNG but my workflow is a mess doing that.

-how can I make windows able to handle these new raw files (.CR2)?

-or what are your suggestions to workaround this files (.CR2)?

Comment: What do you expect to do with Windows? What is your RAW processor?

Comment: @RomeoNinov I'm expecting to see thumbnails of the pictures and to manage them, and my raw processor is LR, with my old camera ( Canon T3 ) I was able to see thumbnails of the raw files

Comment: LR is better place to select and filter your photos. Concentrate there, forget about windows thumbnails

Comment: What version of Windows are you running?

Comment: You understand that RAW is a camera specific format?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen yes sir, but windows used to manage the canon CR2 just like a regular picture, but with the new cameras is no longer possible

Comment: @MorenajeRD You alsounderstand that the software to decipher CR2 800D CR2 image needs to be updated before it can handle formats added since it was installed?

Answer (score 1):

Try Irfanview, or DXO. I'd recommend Irfanview as it is light weight and fast, and I've used it to quickly edit/exclude photos during soccer matches (thousands of photos).